Can not make a copy of appscript file using drive service api or DriveApp
I want to make a copy of a file from a folder using AppScript.
const  copy = (fromFolder, toFolder) => {
  // copy files
  const files = fromFolder.getFiles()
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    const newFile = file.makeCopy(toFolder)
    newFile.setName(file.getName())
  }

  // copy folders
  const folders = fromFolder.getFolders()
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    const  folder = folders.next()
    const newFolder = toFolder.createFolder(folder.getName())
    copy(folder, newFolder)
  }
}

The script works as expected, but it doesn't work when I try to copy Apps Script files in a folder. So, I made a test with the Drive API Service. In my console, I can see all files, even AppScript files. However, when I try to copy them, it doesn't work for AppsScript files. What am I doing wrong?
 const copyResource = (sourceFolderId, targetFolderId) => {
    const params = {
    q: `'${sourceFolderId}' in parents and trashed = false and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`,
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
  };

  const files = Drive.Files.list(params).files;
  console.log(files);

  files.forEach((file) => {
    const resource = {
      title: file.title,
      parents: [{ id: targetFolderId }],
    };
    const newFile = Drive.Files.copy(resource, file.id, {
      supportsAllDrives: true,
    });
  });
};


Can you provide the details of it doesn't work for Apps Script files? For example, did an error message show? By the way, in your showing script, it seems that Drive API v2 is used. Do you enable Drive API v2 at Advanced Google services? If Drive API v3 has been enabled, as a simple modification, please change it to v2 and test it again.

Yeah Drive api service is enabled. There is no message error. It's seems like we can not copy an appscript file in a share drive or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your actual situation and that was not useful, I apologize.

If you're looking for a way to backup you source code files, I have a solution that backs them up as ascii files.  Be glad to share it.

This is just my guess. From your question and your the following reply,

Yeah Drive api service is enabled. There is no message error. It's seems like we can not copy an appscript file in a share drive or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I think that if your showing script of Drive API was for Drive API v2, Drive.Files.list(params).files returns undefined, and an error occurs. But, you say There is no message error.. From this situation, I guessed that you have enabled Drive API v3 at Advanced Google services. If my guess was correct, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
const copyResource = (sourceFolderId, targetFolderId) => {
  const params = {
    q: `'${sourceFolderId}' in parents and trashed = false and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`,
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
    corpora: "allDrives",
  };

  const files = Drive.Files.list(params).files;
  console.log(files);

  files.forEach((file) => {
    const resource = {
      name: file.name,
      parents: [targetFolderId],
    };
    const newFile = Drive.Files.copy(resource, file.id, {
      supportsAllDrives: true,
    });
    console.log(newFile);
  });
};

Note:

You can also see how to enable Drive API v3 at Advanced Google services in this thread.

Reference:

Method: files.copy of Drive API v3


ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION
Similar to the question When copying files using Apps Script from one folder to another any "Apps Script" files being copied end up in MyDrive not the specified folder - why?. It seems that Google Apps Script files tend to be copied over to My Drive instead of the defined destination folder.
I recommend that you submit a bug report to let Google know about the unusual behavior that's going on since I haven't found a report when I searched the Google Issue Tracker.
As a workaround, credit goes to @Tanaike for this. Making sure that Service: googleapis.com/drive/v2 is enabled and using Method: files.update like what was done in the question works, and you may add the following to your first script:
    if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT) {
      Drive.Files.update({ "parents": [{ "id": toFolder.getId() }] }, newFile.getId());
    }
  }

The full code would become:
const copy = (fromFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("abc1234567"), toFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("abc1234567")) => {
  const files = fromFolder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    const newFile = file.makeCopy(toFolder);
    newFile.setName(file.getName());

    if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT) {
      Drive.Files.update({ "parents": [{ "id": toFolder.getId() }] }, newFile.getId());
    }
  }

  const folders = fromFolder.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    const folder = folders.next();
    const newFolder = toFolder.createFolder(folder.getName());
    copy(folder, newFolder);
  }
}

OUTPUT


Thank you so much for the confirmation I wasted so many time thinking I'm doing something wrong.

Can you confirm if the modified first script worked out for you?

Please make sure that you've enabled version 2 of the Google Drive API on your project, since version 3 didn't seem to work when I tested it earlier. You may do so by clicking on Drive under Services + and by making sure that it's on v2 like in this sample image.

Can you confirm if we were able to address your question, @fitMath?
